# How to read the System.ServiceModel.Message?

Tags: wcf, serialization, message

I came across this situation.

Main Function:

```
Message msg = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Default, "Process");
String xmlData ="<Name>Navin</Name>";
Byte[] ba = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(xmlData);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(ba);

XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms);

msg.WriteBody(xw);

readMessage(msg);
```

In readMessage(Message msg):

```
XmlDictionaryReader xdr = msg.GetReaderAtBodyContents();
```

WHen i do this i am getting this error.
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This message cannot suppo
rt the operation because it has been written.

How to overcome this.

Waiting for response.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN [Message.GetReaderAtBodyContents Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.getreaderatbodycontents.aspx), you can't access the message body once it's been read or written - it can only be accessed once. You need to use 'CreateBufferedCopy' to access a message multiple times.

I didn't find any examples in the MSDN documentation, but it looks like you'd need to create a MessageBuffer instance via Message.CreateBufferedCopy, and then you can use the MessageBuffer's CreateMessage method to gain access to the contents of the buffer.

See:

[Message.CreateBufferedCopy Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.message.createbufferedcopy.aspx)

[MessageBuffer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messagebuffer.aspx)

[MessageBuffer.CreateMessage Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.channels.messagebuffer.createmessage.aspx)